# ServletMapping error

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am tried to define multiple servlets in my project, so far there is an authentication and a query servlet:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AuthenticationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>applicationsservices.AuthenticationServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>applicationsservices.QueryServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AuthenticationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/authServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/queryServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is the troublesome QueryServlet.

```
package applicationsservices;

import domain.IAuthenticationProvider;
import domain.User;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    public QueryServlet(){
        super();
        this.userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String query = request.getParameter("queryString");

        response.getWriter().println(query);

    }
}
```

When I try calling it I get a 404 error, whereas the AuthServlet works fine. 
What is wrong with this?

Comment: Turns out that the servlet does not show nullpointerexceptions properly. i wanna die right now

Comment: Why haven't you mapped on your servlet class with @WebServlet("/queryServlet") ?

Comment: I am using JSP and this seemed to be the best way

Comment: I can't get you. If you elaborate your problem you are facing it will be easy for us to solve. If you post your /authServlet we could figure out

Comment: I figured it out, there was a NullPointer in my repository initilization which did not shown up